# how to write angular 6 unit testing for if condition

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How to write unit testing for if the condition, please help me, anyone I tried to like this but it's not covered in my codecoverage

My component

```
isAppListEditable(){
    if(this.requestType === "new"){
      //console.info('inside');
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

my spec file

```
it('isAppListEditable', () => {
    let requestType = "new";
    component.isAppListEditable();
    expect(component.isAppListEditable()).toBeFalsy;
  });
```

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here. What have you try so far ?

Comment: i updated my spec file

Comment: Do you set `requestType` somewhere else in your test?